# Pop Up Menu Segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, menu, segue

I am making a pop up menu in Swift on Xcode 8.2.1, and I can't figure out how to make it segue correctly (It is being created programmatically right now so that it will have a animation when you open it).

```
import UIKit

var clickj = false
var st = String()

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var button = dropDownBtn()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if clickj == true {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: st, sender: nil)
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        //Configure the button
        button = dropDownBtn.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        button.setTitle("Colors", for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        //Add Button to the View Controller
        self.view.addSubview(button)

        //button Constraints
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

        //Set the drop down menu's options
        button.dropView.dropDownOptions = ["Blue", "Choices"]

        }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

protocol dropDownProtocol {
    func dropDownPressed(string : String)
}

class dropDownBtn: UIButton, dropDownProtocol {

    func dropDownPressed(string: String) {
        print(string)
        st = string
        clickj = true
        self.dismissDropDown()
    }

    var dropView = dropDownView()

    var height = NSLayoutConstraint()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

        dropView = dropDownView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        dropView.delegate = self
        dropView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        self.superview?.addSubview(dropView)
        self.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: dropView)
        dropView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        dropView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        dropView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        height = dropView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
    }

    var isOpen = false
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if isOpen == false {

            isOpen = true

            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])

            if self.dropView.tableView.contentSize.height > 150 {
                self.height.constant = 150
            } else {
                self.height.constant = self.dropView.tableView.contentSize.height
            }


            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.dropView.center.y += self.dropView.frame.height / 2
            }, completion: nil)

        } else {
            isOpen = false

            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])
            self.height.constant = 0
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.dropView.center.y -= self.dropView.frame.height / 2
                self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)

        }
    }

    func dismissDropDown() {
        isOpen = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])
        self.height.constant = 0
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.dropView.center.y -= self.dropView.frame.height / 2
            self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class dropDownView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

    var dropDownOptions = [String]()

    var tableView = UITableView()

    var delegate : dropDownProtocol!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray


        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.addSubview(tableView)

        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dropDownOptions.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()

        cell.textLabel?.text = dropDownOptions[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.delegate.dropDownPressed(string: dropDownOptions[indexPath.row])
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

}
```

The problem is I have every thing set up to segue properly but I am still working on where I should place the if statement that will segue when the condition is true (mainly I am looking for some function I could place it in that would be called in the main ViewController when the button is clicked).

Comment: Are you trying to perform a segue in `viewDidLoad()`? Or just in response to a `dropDownOption` being selected in the table view?

Comment: I am trying to preform  the segue inside the `ViewController` class, albeit not specifically restrained to the `viewDidLoad()` method. The only thing I do want to restrict is that you don't end up overlaying buttons. so response to `dropDownOption` being clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close... about all you need is to implement another delegate protocol.

Currently, your `dropDownView` is using `dropDownProtocol` to tell the button that a row was selected. What you also want is a protocol so the button can tell the view controller that it has dismissed itself, and to pass the selected string from the table.

Here is the code you presented, with very few changes. See the comments in the code. With your start, things should be pretty clear - feel free to ask for clarification if needed:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,  dropDownCallBackProtocol {

    var button = dropDownBtn()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Configure the button
        button = dropDownBtn.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        button.setTitle("Colors", for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        //Add Button to the View Controller
        self.view.addSubview(button)

        //button Constraints
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

        //Set the drop down menu's options
        button.dropView.dropDownOptions = ["Blue", "Choices"]

        // set the button's "vcCallBackDelegate"
        button.vcCallBackDelegate = self

    }

    func dropDownCompleted(string: String) {
        print("Inside View Controller:", string)
        // this will be called when the un-show-drop-down animation is finished
        // so you can perform your segue here
        // performSegue(withIdentifier: string, sender: nil)
    }

}

// protocol for the button to "call back" to the view controller (its parent)
protocol dropDownCallBackProtocol {
    func dropDownCompleted(string : String)
}

// protocol for the table to "call back" to the button (its parent)
protocol dropDownProtocol {
    func dropDownPressed(string : String)
}

class dropDownBtn: UIButton, dropDownProtocol {

    var vcCallBackDelegate: dropDownCallBackProtocol?

    func dropDownPressed(string: String) {
        print("Inside button class:", string)
        self.dismissDropDown(string)
    }

    var dropView = dropDownView()

    var height = NSLayoutConstraint()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

        dropView = dropDownView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        dropView.delegate = self
        dropView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        self.superview?.addSubview(dropView)
        self.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: dropView)
        dropView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        dropView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        dropView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        height = dropView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
    }

    var isOpen = false
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if isOpen == false {
            isOpen = true
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])
            if self.dropView.tableView.contentSize.height > 150 {
                self.height.constant = 150
            } else {
                self.height.constant = self.dropView.tableView.contentSize.height
            }
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.dropView.center.y += self.dropView.frame.height / 2
            }, completion: nil)
        } else {
            isOpen = false

            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])
            self.height.constant = 0
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.dropView.center.y -= self.dropView.frame.height / 2
                self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)

        }
    }

    func dismissDropDown(_ selectedString: String) {
        isOpen = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])
        self.height.constant = 0
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.dropView.center.y -= self.dropView.frame.height / 2
            self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: {
            b in
            // tell the delegate the animation is complete, and pass the selected string
            self.vcCallBackDelegate?.dropDownCompleted(string: selectedString)
        })
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class dropDownView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

    var dropDownOptions = [String]()

    var tableView = UITableView()

    var delegate : dropDownProtocol!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray


        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.addSubview(tableView)

        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dropDownOptions.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()

        cell.textLabel?.text = dropDownOptions[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.delegate.dropDownPressed(string: dropDownOptions[indexPath.row])
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: It goes to a blank white screen then quits the app.

Comment: Running that code as-is? Or did you make any edits? If I create a new single-view project, past that code into the default ViewController.swift file, and run it, it works fine (outputs the selected text in the debug console).

Comment: No i didn't change anything except the comment that commented out the code that was supposed to segue, although i did run it on a simulator maybe a real device would work better.

Comment: Ok I ran it on a real device and got the error: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT.  and yes I ran it without the segue like you did to test it nor have I changed a bit of the code.

Comment: If you're using Xcode 8.2.1, it's possible there is something Swift 4 specific in there... do you see any warnings when running it?

Comment: No warnings only the Thread 1: signal SIGABRT. But I can not use anything above Xcode 8.2.1 (I am doing this at school and I don't own a laptop or anything and the school computer I am using is version 10.11.6)

Comment: Not sure what to tell you then. Step through in debug... find out exactly what line is causing the crash.

Comment: Ok i'll try to do that.

Comment: Well there is a lot of errors but they're all on lines of hexadecimal in Thread 1.

Comment: such as:  ->  0x227bac5c <+8>:  blo    0x227bac74                ; <+32>
    0x27113188 <+144>: mov    r0, r5  class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { and     0x226e7872 <+2>: bl     0x2270efa0                ; exit

Comment: Uh so I am going to show what is in the console but I have to split it because it is to many characters for a comment

Comment: 2018-04-12 07:33:39.223 Pop Up Menu Test[901:340252] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Pop_Up_Menu_Test.ViewController 0x14688b60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key test.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x22b2f91b 0x222cae17 0x22b2f629 0x232a31f3 0x2740e8b7 0x232b56d3 0x2755fe9b 0x22a791cb 0x2755ebd1 0x27411aa3 0x271e4ffb 0x270aaa1f 0x270aa971 0x270b1639 0x270aeb3d 0x27123a5d 0x273473bb 0x2734b285 0x2735f83d 0x273487b3

Comment: 0x241d2c07 0x241d2ab9 0x241d2db9 0x22af1dff 0x22af19ed 0x22aefd5b 0x22a3f229 0x22a3f015 0x27118c3d 0x27113189 0xff23c 0x226e7873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: So I put all of that in a hexadecimal to ASCII converter here's what I got: "²ù",®"²ö)#*1ó'@è·#+VÓ'Uþ"§Ë'UëÑ'A£'Oû'
ª'
©q'9'
ë=':]'4s»'4²'5ø='4³$,$*¹$-¹"¯ÿ"¯í"®ý["£ò)"£ð'='1ÿ#"nxs

Comment: or if you use octal you get: 2 3-- 93S�;



 K7;

Comment: OK - did you start with a new ViewController? That error indicates the ViewController has a key "test" but the class does not. Had you created IBOutlets or something? If so, you need to remove them. I'd suggest creating a new project and just use this code in the default created view controller... see what happens.